# How can I change the NoData value in QGIS 2.x using the python console

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, qgis-2

I'm trying to add a NoData value to a single band raster image in QGIS 2.0 using the python console but can't find the right bit of code to do it.

Here's what I see on the console:

```
>>> layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
>>> layer
<qgis.core.QgsRasterLayer object at 0x06AFFDF8>
>>> layer.renderer()
<qgis.core.QgsPalettedRasterRenderer object at 0x1874E0C0>
```

Any help here would be great!